# AWS Media Live - handle stream start and stop events

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming, streaming, aws-media-live, aws-mediaservices

I cannot find any information how to handle the situation like this:

Stream starts: about 3 o'clock.

1.Before the person who is streaming (let's call him a streamer) start to stream I would like to have static image saying something like: 'The event will start soon'.

2.Streamer start pushing his stream to RTMP endpoint but he's late and starts at 3.02. Up until 3.02 the same picture should be visible (as in point 1).

3.Streamer should finish at 4 o'clock but he finishes 5 minutes before 4 (pushing `stop` at his device).

4.Now, ending screen should be visible from 5 minutes to four and later.

I know that inputs should be switched in order to change a view and this can be scheduled for fixed time, but I would like this to be switched dynamically, ie. when streamer starts pushing to RTMP URL and stops pushing to RTMP URL (from eg. Larix software). How to handle that in AWS Media Live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for asking this question on stackoverflow, the easiest way to achieve what you are looking to do is by using an Input Prepare Scheduled Action.  The channel will then monitor the input and raise an alarm if the RTMP source is not there.  When the RTMP source begins then the alarm will remit, you can send the alarms to a lambda that will look for these alarms and can do the switch from slate MP4 to the RTMP source when it sees the RTMP input missing alarm was cleared.  This can also be done for when RTMP input goes away.

Information on Prepare Inputs:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/feature-prepare-input.html

Global configuration - Input loss behavior:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/creating-a-channel-step3.html

Zach

Comment: Thank you so much Zachay! And in order to receive an alert in lambda function should I use CloudWatch Events?

Comment: Hi Murakami, yes you will want to use CloudWatch Events here is a nice blog post that discusses how to use CloudWatch to generate a Lambda Function.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/monitoring-aws-media-services-using-amazon-cloudwatch-events/